# Why sourcepath in i18n doesn't work in Yii2 advance

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

```
    <?php
return [
    'sourcePath' => __DIR__. '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
];
```

i've try using

`'sourcePath' => __DIR__. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'..',`

but it's not show the frontend and backend folder

this is my full code in common\i18n

```
<?php
return [
    'sourcePath' => __DIR__. '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    'languages' => ['en-EN','id-ID'], //Add languages to the array for the language files to be generated.
    'translator' => 'Yii::t',
    'sort' => false,
    'removeUnused' => false,
    'only' => ['*.php'],
    'except' => [
        '.svn',
        '.git',
        '.gitignore',
        '.gitkeep',
        '.hgignore',
        '.hgkeep',
        '/messages',
        '/vendor',
    ],
    'format' => 'php',
    'messagePath' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'messages',
    'overwrite' => true,
];
```

The error show like this
Error: The source path ../.. is not a valid directory.

Comment: Where are the translation files stored?

Comment: translation files stored in common/messages @atymic

Answer (score 0):

I think you sourcePath is wrong. You are missing one DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

```
'sourcePath' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
```